# scikit learn linearsvc confidence

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, liblinear

I'm using scikit-learn's LinearSVC SVM implementation, and I'm trying understand the multi-class prediction.  Looking at coef_ and intercept_ I can get the hyperplane weights.  For example, on my learning problem with two features and four labels I get

```
f0 =  1.99861379*x1 - 0.09489263*x2 + 0.89433196
f1 = -2.04309715*x1 - 3.51285420*x2 - 3.1206355
f2 =  0.73536996*x1 + 2.52111207*x2 - 3.04176149
f3 = -0.56607817*x1 - 0.16981337*x2 - 0.92804815
```

When I use the decision_function method I get the values that correspond to the above functions.  But the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function) says

> The confidence score for a sample is the signed distance of that
>   sample to the hyperplane.

But decision_function does not return the signed distance, it just returns f().

To be more specific, I'm assuming that the LinearSVC uses the standard trick of having a constant 1 feature to represent a threshold.  (This might be wrong.)  For my example problem this gives a three dimensional feature space where instances are always of the form (1,x1,x2).  Assuming no other threshold term, the algorithm learns a hyperplane w=(w0, w1, w2) that goes through the origin in this three dimensional space.  Now I get a point to predict, call it z=(1,a,b).  What is the signed distance (margin) of this point to the hyperplane.  It's just dot(w,z)/2norm(w).  The LinearSVC code is returning dot(w,z)

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `Therefore those functions should not give the distances`what do you mean by that ?

Comment: I added a paragraph to the end of my question to answer your issue.  In short, I'm claiming that the decision_function method returns dot(w,x) when it should return dot(w,x)/||w||.